# How do I get only the documents that dont have 'false' in an array of boolean values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have these documents:

```
[
    {
        _id: 132143124,
        orders: [true, false, false],
    },
    {
        _id: 3123,
        orders: [true, true, true],
    },
];
```

How do I get only the documents that dont have 'false' in their orders array.
I need an aggregate stage solution. ( MongoDB aggregate solution )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$not` or `$ne` ( as Mongo's query language flattens arrays ) for this, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  orders: {$ne: false}
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WsHrLDl8Hgn)

same syntax will work in the aggregation pipeline:
[Mongo Playground Aggregation](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LOSg83w8Df0)

Comment: `orders: {$ne: false }` should also work

Comment: true, even easier.

Comment: Wow thanks. I was using the wrong syntax for this. I was writing something like this :
`{false : {$not : {$in : orders } } }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter function for arrays:

```js
const results = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    orders: [true, false, false],
  }, {
    _id: 2,
    orders: [true, true, true],
  }
]
    
const filtered_results = results.map(({orders, ...data}) => {
  return {
    orders: orders.filter((order)=>order === true), 
    ...data
  }
})
    
console.log(filtered_results)
```